# catkin set warning lvl

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

how i can set my warning level when i am using catkin_make?

i get no warnings at the moment.

thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80126/catkin-set-warning-lvl/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about compiler warnings, you can pass arguments to `cmake` or `make` via `catkin_make`:

```
 $ catkin_make --cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wall"
```

Should enable all the warnings, for example.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-09-17**:
when i use this i get
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
CXX_FLAGS

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-18**:
That should have been `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, I updated my answer.

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-09-18**:
thank you it is working :)